# swift background color animation loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, animation, colors

I want the background color of my iOS app to change between four colors over x amount of seconds

This is what I have so far (it does exactly what I want when I specify just 2 colors)

I also need the animation to run in a loop infinitely.

*ViewController.swift*

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(X.0, animations: {
        // Color 1
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba)
        // Color 2
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba)
        // Color 3
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba)
        // Color 4
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba)

    })
```

Comment: Please try with my solution. Using animation completion blocks are always better than running a timer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this out:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                            }, completion:nil)
                })
        })
}
```

In case you want a continuous repeating animation, try this out:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.0, options:[UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat, UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse], animations: {
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
     self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The only problem with the second solution is that it skips the first two colors, it just switches between gray and red

Comment: Transition is too quick to see the change actually. You may use completion block and play with duration to fit your need if you want to go with option 2.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped! Cheers :-)!

Comment: An important note here is that the animation MUST be called in `viewDidAppear` otherwise it won't have any effect at all.

Comment: very nice effect,  I can't get it to repeatedly animate under Swift 3, using .repeat, .autoreverse. and the newer animate(withDuration ... syntax. Anything I must be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

**Below code helps to keep enable user interaction with animated view. A random color generation (use in case its needed).**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(7, delay: 1, options:
                         [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
                          UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat,
                          UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse],
        animations: {
           self.yourView.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
           self.yourView.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
        }, completion:nil )

func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, 
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `NSTimer`:

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update() {
    let nextCollor = getNextColor()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(X.0, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = nextCollor
    })
}

func getNextColor() -> UIColor {
    let currentColor = self.view.backgroundColor

    if currentColor == smaple1 {
        return UIColor.redColor()
    } else if currentColor == smaple2 {
        return UIColor.grayColor()
    } else {
        return UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

`NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` runs your code every 5 seconds

PS: do not forget invalidate timer when you done with it. Just call `timer.invalidate()` for it. Otherwise you get a crash.

Comment: Okay cool thanks. I'm new to swift.. what would a getNextColor function look like?

Comment: @user3390658 check out update. but it's not the best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.customButton.backgroundColor = .red
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
        self.customButton.backgroundColor = .none
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a dynamic / unknown amount of colors to cycle through, so i refactored the Swift 5 answer a bit:

**Swift 5**

```
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse]) {
                // colors is the dynamic [UIColor] array previously defined
                for color in colors {
                    self.colorView.backgroundColor = color
                }
            } completion: { (finished) in
                
            }
```

this will nicely cycle through the colors with a fade-style animation -- and with the .autoreverse option, it won't "snap" to the starting color.